# How to hide the y axis in msstackedcolumn2dlinedy fusion charts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `msstackedcolumn2dlinedy` fusion charts.

Please check out this fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/rSemD/)

what i'm trying to do is i need to hide the right side y axis value in this chart. How can i do that ?

[image: Check the Fusion chart here]

**Tried**

```
          //"sYAxisName": "Profit %",
           // "sNumberSuffix": "%",
           // "sYAxisMaxValue": "25",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you need to change the type of the fusion chart.

Check [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rSemD/215/)

Change to this   `type: 'msstackedcolumn2d',` instead of  `type: 'msstackedcolumn2dlinedy',`

It will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, but if somebody does come along having the same issue I had, here is my solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/ex10w9d7/22/

I added this to the charts field:

`"showDivLineSecondaryValue": "0", "showSecondaryLimits": "0",`

And also removed the name of the secondary axis:

`//"syaxisname":"name to be removed"`

This removed the y-axis labels without removing the line that I wanted